# How not to show data in a Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

[image: Image showing the data and the pivot associated with the data]

This table has 3 cases. First, where data for the group and each region and state under it is present, second, data for the group is absent but for each region and state is present, and third, data for group is present but the same is absent for each region and state. I have created a pivot below the data from the same. What I would like to do is, not to show the group data when data for group, region and state are all present because then it is taking the group as a separate entity and adding it to the total (towards the bottom of the pivot, for US group). Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure what you want, since you are only stating what you do not want...
What should show up... region + rev

Comment: For US Group, when I collapse it, it should show sum of Alabama and Ohio and not anothe US Group item below.